# Game play at multiple layers simultaneously in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using 3 CCLayers in one Scene and I want simultaneous game play on all three layers, while user will play the game by switching between these layers. I can switch between these layers easily but my scheduled methods are not being called at all

Thats how I am doing it in the init() method of my scene and the line [self schedule:@selector(gameLogic:) interval:1.0]; is not working for me

Please help me where I am getting it wrong.

```
    layer1 = [CCLayer node];
    layer2 = [CCLayer node];
    layer3 = [CCLayer node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [self addChild:layer1];
    [self addChild:layer2];
    [layer2 setVisible:NO];
    [self addChild:layer3];
    [layer3 setVisible:NO];

    CCLabelTTF *layer1Label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Layer1" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:64];
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    layer1Label.position =  ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );
    [layer1 addChild: layer1Label];

    CCLabelTTF *layer2Label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Layer2" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:64];
    layer2Label.position =  ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );
    [layer2 addChild: layer2Label];

    CCLabelTTF *layer3Label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Layer3" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:64];
    layer3Label.position =  ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );
    [layer3 addChild: layer3Label];

    [self schedule:@selector(gameLogic:) interval:1.0];

}
return self;
```

}

Comment: there does not seems to be any problem with your code - which you have shared.

Comment: I am of the similar opinion but don't know why gameLogic method doesn't gets called for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh dear I got it set myself. The problem was nowhere in init(). [super onEnter] was missing in -(void)onEnter method. Now all my scheduled methods are doing fine.